# Wireless networking on Gnome on Ubuntu 9 / 10

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wifi, gnome

So here's my problem: I have some netbooks (ASUS eee, and ACER Aspire Ones) that I've been tasked to set up as kiosk machines, locked up tight
for normal users. 
I am a command-line, server man, so this gnome malarkey is all a bit new to me.
I found a lovely 9.04 kiosk livecd that installs and runs *exactly* as I want it to, but I can't get the wireless working.
So I dropped on a full 10.4 distro, and wireless works straight out of the box (so hardware is good) - all I needed to do was right-click
on the network connection icon, enter my SSID and password (WPA/WPA2) and away it went, perfect.
Further investigation on 10.4 distro shows that /etc/networking/interfaces is virtually empty (just

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

in it), even after I have set up the wireless thru the gnome taskbar applet (is that the right word?).
So where does gnome / ubuntu store the network settings to bring the blasted wireless connection up, and what do I need to 
do on the kiosk version to get wireless running?

Answer (score 1):

From [Ubuntuguide.org](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Karmic#Wireless):

> ### Wireless
>
> #### Network Manager
>
> Network Manager has been redesigned for Ubuntu and now works quite well. You should not require other network managers, and, in fact, more than one network manager can cause conflicts.
>   It can be accessed from the tray icon.
>
> #### Manual configuration from the command-line
>
> 3 steps for WEP:
>
> ```
> sudo iwconfig eth[N] essid [SSID]
> sudo iwconfig eth[N] key restricted s:[PASSWORD]
> sudo dhclient
> ```
>
> WPA is more complicated:
>
> ```
> su
> mkdir /etc/wpa_supplicant
> cd /etc/wpa_supplicant
> echo network = { > wpa_supplicant.conf
> echo ssid="SSID" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
> echo key_mgmt=WPA-PSK >> wpa_supplicant.conf
> echo psk="PRESHAREDKEY" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
> echo } >> wpa_supplicant.conf
> cd /etc/network
> vim interfaces
> ```
>
> Now add after "auto eth[N] ..." & "iface eth[N] .." (press 'i'):
>
> ```
> wpa-driver wext # or whatever driver your network card needs
> wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
> ```
>
> Save the file ('Esc', ':x', 'Enter') and restart your system.

Comment: But what I don't understand is how it is working on my Lucid setup: /etc/network.interfaces has no wpa lines, and no /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf - /etc/wpa_supplicant contains only action_wpa.sh, functions.sh and ifupdown.sh, and yet, wireless works! iwlist scanning shows details for wpa for wlan0. 
Still confused!

Comment: Network Manager stores system connections in `/etc/Network Manager/system-connections/`.  I'm not sure where it stores user connections, but that shouldn't matter for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `cnetworkmanager` package. It'll let you interface with Network Manager right from the command line.